# How to filter an Array of nested objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array for **recipes** and inside of it I have another Array **ingredients** with some objects, what I want is to filter the **recipes** array by comparing the nested object key **ingredient** with entered value in the Input field (keyup event is working and I have the values form the input fild stored in a variable called **enteredValue** )...

Soo can you help me find how to filter **recipes** using those nested array

```js
const recipes = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Limonade de Coco",
    "servings": 1,
    "ingredients": [{
        "ingredient": "Lait de coco",
        "quantity": 400,
        "unit": "ml"
      },
      {
        "ingredient": "Jus de citron",
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ],
    "time": 10,
    "description": "Mettre les glaçons à votre goût dans le blender, ajouter le lait, la crème de coco, le jus de 2 citrons et le sucre. Mixer jusqu'à avoir la consistence désirée",
    "appliance": "Blender",
    "ustensils": ["cuillère à Soupe", "verres", "presse citron"]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Poisson Cru à la tahitienne",
    "servings": 2,
    "ingredients": [{
        "ingredient": "Thon Rouge (ou blanc)",
        "quantity": 200,
        "unit": "grammes"
      },
      {
        "ingredient": "Concombre",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "ingredient": "Tomate",
        "quantity": 2
      },
      {
        "ingredient": "Lait de Coco",
        "quantity": 100,
        "unit": "ml"
      }
    ],
    "time": 60,
    "description": "Découper le thon en dés, mettre dans un plat et recouvrir de jus de citron vert (mieux vaut prendre un plat large et peu profond). Laisser reposer au réfrigérateur au moins 2 heures. (Si possible faites-le le soir pour le lendemain. Après avoir laissé mariner le poisson, coupez le concombre en fines rondelles sans la peau et les tomates en prenant soin de retirer les pépins. Rayer la carotte. Ajouter les légumes au poissons avec le citron cette fois ci dans un Saladier. Ajouter le lait de coco. Pour ajouter un peu plus de saveur vous pouver ajouter 1 à 2 cuillères à soupe de Crème de coco",
    "appliance": "Saladier",
    "ustensils": ["presse citron"]
  }
]

let filteredRecettesIngrediants = recipes.map(receipt => {
  return receipt.ingredients.filter(ingredientKey => {
    return (ingredientKey.ingredient === 'Carotte')
  })
})

console.log(filteredRecettesIngrediants)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get every recipe which contains the entered ingredient, try this:

```
recipes.filter(r => r.ingredients.some(i => i.ingredient === enteredValue));
```

This gets all items in `recipes` where at least one item in `ingredients` has a value for `ingredient` that is equal to `enteredValue`.

Comment: Thank you very much man, my problem was NOT USING the ''some" method, it is working, thank you again

Comment: Glad it helped. Yeah "some" is very useful, there's also "every" when you want to check that every element in the array matches a condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.ingredients.some(ingred => ingred.ingredient == inputValue))
```

The `some` method returns true if at least one entry satisfies the function given, in this case that the value of `"ingredient"` in each ingredient in the recipe has a value of `inputValue`. If at least one entry returns true then the recipe contains that ingredient so you can add the whole recipe to the filtered output list.

Comment: Thank you very much it is working when i use ''some" method